# How to remove :ns from xmlns:ns using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to create a XML in SQL like this

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com http://www.example.com /media/XSD/123.xsd">
  <Header>
    <Node1>Test</Node1>
  </Header>
</Root>
```

For that I have used the code

```
declare @xml xml
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi,  'http://www.example.com ' as ns)
select 
    @xml = ((SELECT 'Test' as Node1   
             FOR XML PATH('Header'), ROOT('Root')));

set @xml.modify('insert(attribute xsi:schemaLocation {"http://www.example.com  http://www.example.com /media/XSD/123.xsd"}) into (/Root)[1]')                               
select @xml
```

But the output is like this:

```
<Root xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com " xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com  http://www.example.com /media/XSD/123.xsd">
  <Header>
    <Node1>Test</Node1>
  </Header>
</Root>
```

How can I remove `:ns` from `xmlns:ns`?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this XML namespace as the **default** namespace (instead of specifying a `ns` prefix):

```
DECLARE @xml XML

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,
                    DEFAULT 'http://www.example.com')
SELECT
    @xml = ((SELECT 'Test' as Node1   
             FOR XML PATH('Header'), ROOT('Root')));

SET @xml.modify('insert(attribute xsi:schemaLocation {"http://www.example.com  http://www.example.com /media/XSD/123.xsd"}) into (/Root)[1]');
```

This gives you the desired output of:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Node1>Test</Node1>
  </Header>
</Root>
```

Comment: I have tried with 'default ' but at that time I lost the attribute  xsi:schemaLocationin  from Root node

Comment: @Anuja: well, you still need to call your `set @xml.modify ...` after this `SELECT` statement, of course - that will add this `xsi:schemaLocation` tag back into your XML ...

Comment: @Anuja: can't see your problem - it works just fine for me - SQL Server 2014 in my case.

Comment: while executing the sql script that you provides gives me the out put as<Root xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Node1>Test</Node1>
  </Header>
</Root>

Comment: I am using sql Server 2012

Comment: @Anuja: are you using **exactly** what I posted?? Seems you have modified my SQL a little bit (extra `;` in there, no `http://` prefix for namespace).....

Comment: I have tried with out using ;   but the result is same :(